# Simple TDD Jasmine / Karma test failing as undefined function

Tags: javascript, tdd, jasmine, bdd, karma-runner

I'm completely new to jasmine / karma and having a few problems.  Test run fine when i run a simple

```
describe('JavaScript addition operator', function () {
    it('adds two numbers together', function () {
        expect(1 + 2).toEqual(3);
    });
});
```

test, it passes and is ok but I want to now start testing functions in my othe files, Naturally I started with the most difficult one and fell flat on my face.  I then worked my way down the list / errors until I got to the most basic of functions, one that rounds a number to a decimal place by taking in the params.  It gave me an undefined error, so I then thought I'd move the addition test that worked into that file just to see if I was being special and it doesn't work either so can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? :)

I've been hunting online for quite a while and haven't yet found an idiots guide.  I'd like to be able to test my functions by passing in params that I'd expect.  For ex:

```
describe("round results", function(){

    var myFunc = roundresult(a,b);
    var a = 99.923232;
    var b = 1;

    it("rounds the result to dec places", function(){
        expect(myFunc(a,b).toEqual(99.9));
    });
});
```

where this is the function:

```
function roundResult(value, places) {
   var multiplier = Math.pow(10, places);
   return (Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier);
}
```

the error:

```
ReferenceError: roundresult is not defined
at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9878/base/tests/objectTests.js:98:18)
at jasmine.Env.describe_ (http://localhost:9878/absolute/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:884:21)
at jasmine.Env.describe (http://localhost:9878/absolute/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:869:15)
at describe (http://localhost:9878/absolute/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:629:27)
at http://localhost:9878/base/tests/objectTestTests.js:96:1
```

Any help is hugely appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `describe` block, `roundresult` should be `roundResult`.

SOLVED: the order in which you require your files determines whether a statement has been defined by the time you try to invoke it. Use plnkr.co to host a sample with multiple files.

Comment: Hi, I was hoping for a second that I'd been stupidly dumb but I get the same error when changed : ReferenceError: roundResult is not defined

Comment: without seeing the rest of your code it's difficult to tell, but it's likely that the `roundResult` function expressing is being declared in closure scope that is inaccessible to your `describe` block.

Comment: can you suggest how I might be able to make it accessible? I just added the file location to the karma include directly instead of relying on *.js but same result.
So I then moved the function into a file within the same folder as the tests, this time it runs but gives an error of "TypeError: number is not a function" at  expect(myFunc2(a,b).toEqual("99.9"));

Comment: The problem now is why does it matter that it;'s contained within that folder?  I obviously don't want to move all functions there so I'm guessing there must be a config issue somewhere?

Comment: the order in which you require your files determines whether a statement has been defined by the time you try to invoke it. Use http://plnkr.co/ to host a sample with multiple files.

Comment: i hadn't included the js files in the subfolders.  thanks for the help, much appreciated! :) - could you edit the answer in case someone else stumbles across this?

Answer (score 0):

expect(myFunc(a,b).toEqual(99.9)); // incorrect, should be as mentioned below

expect().toEqual();

And you have called the function and than initialize variables, which is also incorrect:

var myFunc = roundresult(a,b);

var a = 99.923232;

var b = 1;

Please have a look how I have done :

// I have created test.js

> describe("round results", function(){     var a = 99.923232;
>
> var b = 1;
>       var myfunc = roundResult(a,b);
>
> ```
> it("rounds the result to dec places", function(){
>     expect(myfunc).toEqual(99.923232);
> });
> ```
>
> });

// main.js

> function roundResult(value, places) {
>   var multiplier = value * places;
>   return multiplier;
>   }

I hope it will resolve your error.

Thanks.